# VS-Code add "umd" to my imports

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

im working on a ionic / angular project. Im working with visual-studio code.

The problem that i have is the following:

if i use the intellisense to import a used type, visual studio code add "/umd" to my imports and the build crashes.

e.g:

this:

```
import { ViewController, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
```

becomes this:

```
import { ViewController, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular/umd';
```

how can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: You can install [Auto import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) or be careful for a few times (once the correct libraries are imported, VSCode will chose them over the `umd` ones). Consider opening an issue on VSCode's repo too !

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i will give Auto import a try.  "once the correct libraries are imported, VSCode will chose them over the umd ones" - no, for my case i have the correct import at the beginning and then when i try to import another type of the same module it will change it to umd. I will open an issue on their repo.